# CSS transition from fixed to absolute with change in top not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a fixed top header bar on my blog. I want another header bar show on the top of the first header when user scrolls down a particular point.

I'm achieving it with jQuery Waypoints. It's working fine.

I've added transition so that when it appears it slides down. It works fine too.

But the problem is when I scroll up, the transition doesn't happen.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="share-bar" class="sticky-wrapper">This is second header</div>
<div id="header">This is normal header</div>
<p id="trigger">THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE SECOND BAR COMES UP</p>
```

JS

```
$('#trigger').waypoint(function(){
    $( "#share-bar" ).toggleClass("stuck");
});
```

CSS

```
#header {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#share-bar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.sticky-wrapper { position:absolute; top:-55px; }    
.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

I've a [working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/tqjSm/)

My question is:

1. Why does the transition work from -55px absolute to 0 fixed but not vice versa?

What am I doing wrong? Please guide me. I'm stuck.

Comment: The transition does happen. Scroll up very fast and you'll catch it. Explanation: when the header switches from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`, `top: 0` in both cases it automaticaly moves to the top of the container it's relative to. That is why it seems like the transition does not happen. It actually does happen, but the element is no longer in viewport

Comment: Then how to get the sliding up effect?

Comment: @mbrrw's answer works for me... You might need to add browser-specific prefixes to your transition property in CSS. (-moz, -o, -webkit)

Comment: I added the properties, it works on Chrome, not on Firefox. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/tqjSm/5/

Comment: remove `position: absolute` from `.sticky-wrapper`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone. I solved it by moving the z-index too. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moving

```
'position: fixed;'
'z-index: 999;'
```

to `#share-bar` and off `.stuck` fixes that.

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqjSm/3/)

Comment: We also need to move z-index. Please edit your answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer.